# Python: Extract contours/boundries into a new image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a binary image with alot of blobs in different shapes. I use python and OpenCV and I got rotated bounding boxes and "more exact" contours. Here is the code. Mult2 is a binary image and "gray" is the same image with a different name (bad, i know).

```
# "rect" gives bounding box centroid coordinates, width/length, angle
ret, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    if 5<cv2.contourArea(cnt)<50000: 
        # Draw smaller objects with rectangular boxes (note that I actually draw all objects and not only the small ones atm)
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(mult2,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
        if 1000<cv2.contourArea(cnt)<500000:
        # Draw bigger objects with help from perimeter lenght ish something
            epsilon = 0.004*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
            cv2.drawContours(mult2,[approx],0,(255,0,0),2)
```

And the result is [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYIma.png)

In this example both the bounding boxes and the contours are drawn, but that does not matter atm. What I want is to draw, or extract, the bounding boxes (in blue), so that the result is that the bounding boxes "replaces" the blobs. I want to do be able to do the same thing with the contours (in red) and place them in the same image (so for a certain blob I want either the bounding box or the contour). How do I do this?

Edit: It cannot be seen here, but in the original binary image there are places where the bounding boxes overlaps each other. So for example one blob can have a big U-shape and sometimes there exist a blob within the U so to speak. In that case I want the contour from the U and the bounding box of the blob inside. How to separate those is already solved, my problem is to extract them. Thank you